# Is it possible to disable one of the direction arrows in a spinbox tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I disable the direction of one of the up or down arrows so that I can simply cycle through values using just one of the arrows? With the arrow disabled.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
spinbox=tk.Spinbox(self,  values=('1', '2', '3'))
spinbox.config(width='5', wrap=True)
spinbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I have read through lots of documentation but cannot find out how to do this. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The spinbox widget does not have an option to disable a single button, so if you really want that, you will have to create a custom widget with only one button.

Comment: I did get that impression from researching the issue. Thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to disable one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the up and down arrow keys like so.

```
spinbox = Spinbox(root)
spinbox.bind("<Up>", lambda e: "break")
spinbox.bind("<Down>", lambda e: "break")
```